# Play stream shoutcast url aac+ stream using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, aac, shoutcast

Hi there someone know how to stream audio with an acc+ shoutcast url? i tried with this code:

**http://pastebin.ca/2228987**

but without luck, i know theres is something like npr-android-app or tunein that uses some media proxy something like that but it can be possible to integrate a proxy like those app but using phonegap?

thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i started to use native coding with eclipse and i accomplish my goal.

Comment: Did you develop a plugin?